# Magento 2 Admin Menu Fatal Error

Tags: magento2, admin, fatal-error

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0

Sometimes it gives below kind of error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null in {folder
>   path}\magento2\vendor\magento\module-backend\Block\Menu.php on line
>   296

Below is the code from

```
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        $cacheKeyInfo = [
            'admin_top_nav',
            $this->getActive(),
            $this->_authSession->getUser()->getId(), // Giving Error on this Line
            $this->_localeResolver->getLocale(),
        ];
        // Add additional key parameters if needed
        $newCacheKeyInfo = $this->getAdditionalCacheKeyInfo();
        if (is_array($newCacheKeyInfo) && !empty($newCacheKeyInfo)) {
            $cacheKeyInfo = array_merge($cacheKeyInfo, $newCacheKeyInfo);
        }
        return $cacheKeyInfo;
    }
```

Comment: What menu option is it? It almost sounds like an extension is not setup/programmed correctly or you have modified a core file.

Comment: I have created new extension. So need to debug

Comment: After session expire. It's giving error on above code's mentioned line

Comment: ^ is that getcachekeyinfo your code or magento code?

Comment: @Ankit Shah  Did you find out what caused it ? I am having same issue